# I want to get order details from firebase database to firebase recyclerview adapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get all data from firebase and also want to store that data to firebase recyclerview. The code is showing only last entry into recycler view. but when i delete last data from firebase it will showing second last data. OR How do i add child field to firebase recyclerview.

```
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                keys = datas.getKey();

                date = datas.child("date").getValue().toString();
                IsCompleted = datas.child("isCompleted").getValue().toString();
                MobileNoFB = datas.child("mobileNo").getValue().toString();
                //Toast.makeText(YourOrdered.this, "Date is :- " + date + " IsCompleted:- " + IsCompleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                if (MobileNoFB.matches(MobileNumber)) {
                    moDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Pending_Orders").child(keys).child("Orders");

                    // Recyclerview data

                    final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<YourOrderAdapter, YourOrderViewHolder> YORecyclerView = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<YourOrderAdapter, YourOrderViewHolder>
                            (YourOrderAdapter.class, R.layout.client_order, YourOrderViewHolder.class, moDatabase) {

                        @Override
                        protected void populateViewHolder(final YourOrderViewHolder viewHolder, final YourOrderAdapter model, final int position) {

                            viewHolder.setProImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getProductImage());
                            viewHolder.setProductQuantity(model.getProductQuantity());
                            viewHolder.setDate(date);
                            viewHolder.setIsCompleted(IsCompleted);
                            viewHolder.setProductColor(model.getProductColor());
                            viewHolder.setProductNo(model.getProductNo());
                        }
                    };
                    YORecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    mBlogList.setAdapter(YORecyclerView);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(YourOrdered.this, "Ordered does not found...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                //Toast.makeText(YourOrdered.this, "I is:- " + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            //Toast.makeText(YourOrdered.this, "Date is :- " + date + " IsCompleted:- " + IsCompleted,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[image: database structure]

Answer (score 0):

Please remove

```
`mBlogList.setAdapter(YORecyclerView);`
```

from for loop and add it after for loop

```
   `mBlogList.setAdapter(YORecyclerView);`
```

Comment: i just did it but not working. it is showing only last records

Comment: in for loop, you need to all record in the list  and pass this list to your adapter

Comment: currently it is displaying last Record or First Record ?

Comment: Currently it is displaying last record

Comment: then you need to add all the record in list and remove adapter creating from for loop